# I need to convert my array of objects into one object with specific keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nivo-react

Good afternoon. I want to display the months of the year and the amount spent in each category.
Ex:

```
{Month: "January", Food: 610, foodColor: "#063951", Others: 121, othersColor: "#C13018", …}
Food: 610
Health: 233
Month: "January"
Others: 121
Transport: 30
foodColor: "#063951"
healthColor: "#2BC4A9"
othersColor: "#C13018"
transportColor: "#0D95BC"
```

I'm getting from my server an array of objects with all months. Something like that:

```
(43) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "September", category: "Food", price: 610, color: "#063951"}
1: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "September", category: "Health", price: 233, color: "#2BC4A9"}
2: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "September", category: "Transport", price: 30, color: "#0D95BC"}
3: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "September", category: "Others", price: 121, color: "#C13018"}
4: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "October", category: "Health", price: 113, color: "#2BC4A9"}
5: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "October", category: "Transport", price: 330, color: "#0D95BC"}
6: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "October", category: "Others", price: 650, color: "#C13018"}
7: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "October", category: "Food", price: 170.55, color: "#063951"}
```

I've created a function to filter the month:

```
 const getMonth = (month) => {
    let monthData = totalTransactionsPerMonth.filter((transaction) =>{
       return transaction.monthname === `${month}`     
    })

    return monthData;
  }
```

and I'm using it to get the months separately:

```
  let janData = getMonth("January");
  let fevData = getMonth("February");
  let marData = getMonth("March");
  let aprData = getMonth("April");
  let mayData = getMonth("May");
  let junData = getMonth("June");
  let julData = getMonth("July");
  let augData = getMonth("August");
  let sepData = getMonth("September");
  let octData = getMonth("October");
  let novData = getMonth("November");
  let decData = getMonth("December");
```

When I call console.log(janData) I see this:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "January", category: "Health", price: 233, color: "#2BC4A9"}
1: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "January", category: "Transport", price: 30, color: "#0D95BC"}
2: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "January", category: "Others", price: 121, color: "#C13018"}
3: {id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "January", category: "Food", price: 610, color: "#063951"}
```

I want from that array with the months data, (janData, fevData, etc..) create an object like this:

```
const January = {
    month: 
    food: 
    foodColor: 
    others: 
    othersColor:
    transport: 
    transportColor: 
    health: 
    healthColor: 
   }
```

and the values will be filled by the values of the array. I've tried to create a function to receive as argument the monthData and then use the index (Ex: food: monthArgument[3].price) but I get " cannot read price of undefined". I've made some search but I could not find a response. Please, I'm stuck here, could someone help me?

It doesn't seems important to the question but I'm using React, Node, mySQL, Nivo/barChart

Comment: Do you really want to do this one month at a time or are you really just trying to get all months aggregated up?

Comment: Well,  I need in the end, an array of objects and each object will be a different month of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to do this one month at a time. You can take the entire set of data and create all the results in one go.

Basically, the idea is to group by `monthname` using `reduce` and then further reduce the matched rows for each month to form a single object per month.

```js
const input = [{id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "September", category: "Food", price: 610, color: "#063951"},
{id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "September", category: "Health", price: 233, color: "#2BC4A9"},
{id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "September", category: "Transport", price: 30, color: "#0D95BC"},
{id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "September", category: "Others", price: 121, color: "#C13018"},
{id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "October", category: "Health", price: 113, color: "#2BC4A9"},
{id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "October", category: "Transport", price: 330, color: "#0D95BC"},
{id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "October", category: "Others", price: 650, color: "#C13018"},
{id: "zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1", monthname: "October", category: "Food", price: 170.55, color: "#063951"}];

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(input.reduce( (acc, i) => {
  if(!acc[i.monthname]) acc[i.monthname] = [];
  acc[i.monthname].push(i);
  return acc
},{}))
  .map( ([month,rows]) => {  
    return [
      month,
      rows.reduce( (acc, i) => ({...acc, [i.category]: i.price, [i.category + "Color"] : i.color}),{})
    ];
  }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I love you.  I'm feeling pretty dumb right now. I will try to understand what you've suggested. Thank you man.

Answer (score 1):

the following code should do the stuff.

```js
const totalTransactionsPerMonth = [
    {id: 'zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1', monthname: 'September', category: 'Food', price: 610, color: '#063951'}
    , {id: 'zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1', monthname: 'September', category: 'Health', price: 233, color: '#2BC4A9'}
    , {id: 'zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1', monthname: 'September', category: 'Transport', price: 30, color: '#0D95BC'}
    , {id: 'zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1', monthname: 'September', category: 'Others', price: 121, color: '#C13018'}
    , {id: 'zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1', monthname: 'October', category: 'Health', price: 113, color: '#2BC4A9'}
    , {id: 'zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1', monthname: 'October', category: 'Transport', price: 330, color: '#0D95BC'}
    , {id: 'zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1', monthname: 'October', category: 'Others', price: 650, color: '#C13018'}
    , {id: 'zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1', monthname: 'October', category: 'Food', price: 170.55, color: '#063951'}
];

function getMonthData(month) {
    return totalTransactionsPerMonth
        .filter(({monthname}) => month === monthname)
        .reduce((result, row) => {
            const category = row.category.toLowerCase();
            result['month'] = month;
            result[category] = row.price;
            result[`${category}Color`] = row.color;
            return result;
        }, {});
}

console.log(getMonthData('October'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `reduce` with each `month` as the key in the accumulator. Add each `category` and color to each month object

```js
const input=[{id:"zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1",monthname:"September",category:"Food",price:610,color:"#063951"},{id:"zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1",monthname:"September",category:"Health",price:233,color:"#2BC4A9"},{id:"zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1",monthname:"September",category:"Transport",price:30,color:"#0D95BC"},{id:"zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1",monthname:"September",category:"Others",price:121,color:"#C13018"},{id:"zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1",monthname:"October",category:"Health",price:113,color:"#2BC4A9"},{id:"zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1",monthname:"October",category:"Transport",price:330,color:"#0D95BC"},{id:"zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1",monthname:"October",category:"Others",price:650,color:"#C13018"},{id:"zxFBMv43ZGgHJpd6a3tjyTO3Rxg1",monthname:"October",category:"Food",price:170.55,color:"#063951"}];

const group = input.reduce((acc, { monthname, category, price, color }) => {
  category = category.toLowerCase();
  acc[monthname] ||= { month: monthname };
  acc[monthname][category] = price
  acc[monthname][category + 'Color'] = color
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(group))
```